# pros and cons of using linq to sql classes to populate the user interface (html)? Is there a way to avoid the mapping?

Tags: c#, linq, orm, linq-to-sql

I have hundreds of linq to sql classes defined in dbml file.
When I am trying to present these data to html, I constantly find the need to display the properties of these classes.
I kind of know that it's not a good idea to use directly these linq to sql classes.
But It also seems a waste of time to define classes which resemble the LINQ TO SQL Classes just for the purpose of displaying their properties in the html.
And also I have to map these linq to sql class into custom defined classes, and when updating, I have to map these custom defined classes into linq to sql class in order to talk with database.
I guess this also applies to other framework, such as nhibernate and entity frameworks/

Is there a better way to manage this?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Questions about "Is it good to use XXXXXX for YYYYYY" are generally too broad/opinion based. You should consider editing the post into more concrete question. As post stands now - feel free to pick any approach you like as long as all people who need to read/work with the code can understand.reason about it and you are able to test it to degree you are happy with.

Comment: I'd love to see the SO community help people when they can instead of just closing their questions. This might be a bit broad, but it's a good question and there is an answer that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on a couple of factors:

**Security**

Is it okay for every property of these L2S classes to be available to the UI? How big is the team? Is there a separate team working on the UI? Is it okay for them to have access to every property? What if they expose a property to the user that they shouldn't? Is that even possible with this app?

**Developer Overhead**

Mapping code sucks. It's overhead that can provide no value if the L2S classes can be exposed to the UI. But only you can answer that with your specific case. It's overhead that can provide tremendous value if security is a concern.

Do these classes have many properties? If so, that can be confusing to the UI developer as they see a lot of noise instead of just what they need. The communication effort increases as middle-tier developers have to answer questions from the UI team about what properties to use.

**Performance**

How many of these classes need to go to the UI? And how much data does each hold? If 90% of the properties of these classes aren't used by the UI, then you may have a lot of unnecessary traffic and latency. This might seem okay at first, but it's dangerous because it can really cause performance issues later as more and more data needs to be sent to the UI.

**Refactoring Time**

Do you have the luxury of being able to refactor if you expose the L2S classes and then find out you should create DTOs instead? If not, maybe you should err on the side of caution. If you can change it later if you find it necessary, then perhaps it's safe to expose the L2S classes and deal with it later if it becomes an issue.